# NextJS middleware can fetch httpOnly cookies only during development?

Tags: cookies, next.js, middleware, vercel, httpcookie

When Using the NextJS _middleware.js cookie is fetched by it during development in localhost, but as soon as I deploy onto vercel it stops fetching the cookie.
The Cookie is httpOnly and the cookie is present on the website but is not being fetched by the middleware in production.
Here is my middleware code

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(req) {
    let token = req.cookies["refreshToken"];
    console.log(token);

    const { origin } = req.nextUrl

    const url = req.url

    if (url.includes('/profile') && !token) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}/`)
    }

    if (token && url.includes('/profile')) {
        return NextResponse.next()
    }

}
```

Any **Suggestions**? or does it not work cross site ?, but I am able to store the cookie, keep that in mind.

Comment: How do you authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a cross-site request issue. If your backend is hosted on a different domain and you set the cookie with the SameSite attribute set to lax or strict, your frontend code won't have access to it (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)).

Comment: ```const cookieConfig = { httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'none', secure: true }```
This is my config for Cookies, i have written that i am able to get the cookie from backend but the middleware is not able to get it.

Comment: Do you have `credentials: include` set in your requests?

Comment: I have fixed the issue, so the domain needs to be same for the client and server side, only then middleware can fetch the cookies, but the cookies still can be stored and sent with a fetch request.

Comment: @thatAwesomeKK do have any code you could share? I'm running into the same issue and can't figure it out.

Comment: There is no code, you need to make one domain for both of your servers, frontend and backend
for e.g., www.example.com - frontend
api.example.com - backend
you can use cloudflare to do that, also i think vercel can now do that in the DOMAIN settings